# template inhereting issues: one template overrides the other

Tags: javascript, typescript, templates, go-templates

I have two HTML templates (login.html, signup.html) and they both inherit the (base.html) file, the problem is that one of the two files is overriding the title and content of the other. Meaning that when I go to /login/ I see the login content, but when i go to /signup/ I see again the Login content! and when i stop (login.html) from extending the base.html the /signup/ shows me the content of the signup page.

I'm still new to Go, building a todo app, so what am I doing wrong here?

base.html:

```
{{define "base"}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<title>{{template "title"}}</title>
...
    {{template "main" .}}
...
{{end}}
```

login.html:

```
{{template "base" .}}
{{define "title"}}Login{{end}}
{{define "main"}}
     Login Now!
{{end}}
```

**Till here everything is working fine**

Now when i started to add more templates: 
signup.html

```
{{template "base" .}}
{{define "title"}}Sign Up{{end}}
{{define "main"}}
    Login or miss who you love >:(
{{end}}
```

## Update: my Go code

main.go (resposible for routing and reusable functions):

package main

```
import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

var templates = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("tmpl/base.html", "tmpl/index.html", "tmpl/signup.html", "tmpl/login.html"))

func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, tmpl string, data interface{}) {
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, tmpl+".html", data)
    if err != nil {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }
}

func main() {
    r := httprouter.New()
    r.GET("/signup/", signupHandler)
    r.POST("/createUser/", createUserHandler)
    r.GET("/login/", loginHandler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r))
}
```

auth.go (Contains handlers for authentication)

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

func signupHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    renderTemplate(w, r, "signup", nil)
}
// Logins
func loginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    renderTemplate(w, r, "login", nil)


    return
    }
    
//===================================================
//===================================================
//===================================================
//===================================================
//===================================================
```

Database code to create user(**Not sure if this is relevant**)

```
//===================================================
//===================================================
//===================================================
//===================================================
 func createUserHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
        if r.FormValue("password1") != r.FormValue("password2") {
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/signup/", http.StatusFound)
            return
        }
        db := connectDB(w, "TodoWoo")
        defer db.Close()
        q := `INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES (?, ?)`
        if _, err := db.Exec(q, r.FormValue("username"), r.FormValue("password1")); err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/login/", http.StatusFound)
    }
    func loginUserHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    
    }
```

driver.go (Connecting database,  **Not sure if this is relevant**

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

// Don't forgot to defer db.Close()
func connectDB(w http.ResponseWriter, scm string) *sql.DB {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", fmt.Sprintf("root:My44200444Sql@(127.0.0.1:3306)/%s?parseTime=true", scm))
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    return db
}
```

Comment: please send us your `golang` code. your controller or your http handler

Comment: Done __________

Comment: What happens if you put `{{ template "base" . }}` *after* you've defined the title & main templates? ([docs](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Nested_template_definitions): *"Template definitions must appear at the top level of the template, much like global variables in a Go program."*)

Comment: I put it at the very bottom of the page and got the same results (after the {{end}} of {{define "main"}}

Comment: @ZeyadShapan in that case what you can do is to split the base into header/footer, remove any reference to main, and instead invoke header/footer at the top/bottom of login & signup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

`base.html`

```
{{define "base_header"}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ . }}</title>
</head>
<body>
{{end}}
    
{{define "base_footer"}}
</body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

`login.html`

```
{{ $page_title := "Login" }}
{{ $page_footer := "login footer text" }}
{{ template "base_header" $page_title }}
Login Now!
{{ template "base_footer" $page_footer }}
```

`signup.html`

```
{{ $page_title := "Sign Up" }}
{{ $page_footer := "signup footer text" }}
{{ template "base_header" $page_title }}
Login or miss who you love >:(
{{ template "base_footer" $page_footer }}
```

---

Comment: What about meta tags, script tags, and link tags? How should those be handled?

Comment: Depends on what you mean. @SapphireSun